# jQuery .click command order

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

This is a very simple question/problem, and I can easily work around it, but since I'm learning javascript I was very eager to know WHY exactly this particular problem is happening.

```
$("#go").click(function() {
    $("p").append(array[x] + " ")
    functionlist[array[x]]()
    x++
})​
```

This does not work as I expect it to. I want it to write the current content of array, perform a simple animation that is associated with a certain function name, and then increment x. Everything works, except it doesn't increment x.

If I do this:

```
$("#go").click(function() {
    $("p").append(array[x] + " ")
    //functionlist[array[x]]()
    x++
})​
```

x is incremented successfully.

So my question is, why does this happen?

Here is a link to a jsfiddle that I am using: http://jsfiddle.net/mxy6N/3/

Comment: `var x = 0` -- you're redeclaring `x` as zero each click.

Comment: I don't think `x` is incremented in the second case either...

Comment: My bad, however my issue still exists if I define x = 0 in the global space.

Comment: no function smooch, throwing error, not executing x++

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: functionlist has no method 'smooch'`

Comment: `smack` is not in the function list either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you check your script console (F12 is most browsers), you'll see that `functionlist[array[x]]()` throws an error something like:

> Object has no method "smooch"

This is because `array[x]` is equal to "smooch", and `functionlist["smooch"]` is undefined, so it errors out before it makes it to your `x++`.

Other things going on in this code:

- x is declared inside of your function, therefore it will always be 0 at the time it is used.
- even if it were declared outside of your function, as you increment it, it will run out of items to look at in your array. You'll need to use a modulo operator or two here.
- You're not referencing an .js files that have a definition for $.fn.transition, so your transition calls will also error out.
- `flip` and `flop` both have the same `rotateY` value, so once it "flips" it won't "flop"

Here is something that might do what you're looking to do: http://jsfiddle.net/g5mJd/3/

And the updated code:

```
var array = ["smooch", "jab", "flip"];
var move = "flip";
var x = 0;
var functionlist = {
    flip: function() {
        $("#block").transition({
            perspective: '0px',
            rotateY: '180deg'
        }, 1000);
    },
    flop: function() {
        $("#block").transition({
            perspective: '0px',
            rotateY: '0deg'
        }, 100);
    }
};


$("#go").click(function() {
    var functionName = (x % 2 == 0) ? 'flip' : 'flop';
    var fn = functionlist[functionName];
    if($.isFunction(fn)) {
        fn();
    }
    var say = array[x % array.length];
    $('p').append(say + ' ');
    x++;
})​;
```

EDIT: Updated with `$.isFunction()` check.

Comment: I'm surprised to see F12 works in Chrome as well. I thought it was an IE9 specialty.

Comment: This is great! Thanks allot. Any hints or pointers to how I would go about making the code realize whether  the content of the array is also the name of a function? (And in that case executing it)?

Comment: @LeMarcin yes, if you're using jQuery, you can do: `$.isFunction(someobj)`... I'll update the answer.

Comment: This is excellent! With $.isFunction I get exactly the results I was looking for. Although the flipping and flopping/the array running out of options weren't part of my intended use, I'm very curious how you got them to loop. Particularly what does [x % array.length] do? I figured out that (x % 2 == 0) ? 'flip' : 'flop'; keeps going between one and the other, but again, how does it do this?

Comment: `%` is the modulo operator.  Basically `a % b` will return the remainder of `a / b`... so `1 % 3 == 1`, `2 % 3 == 2`, `3 % 3 == 0`, `4 % 3 == 1`... it's a trick to infinitely loop through the items in an array:  `while(true) { alert(myArray[i++ % myArray.length]); }`